# Jquery will not work on this basic website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a bit of a test website to try out my html skills, but jquery is not working, it wont do anything, I have tried several different functions. It dosent work in jsfiddle either.

My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript'src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabI">
        <h2>TEST</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tabII">
        <h2>TEST</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tabIII">
        <h2>TEST</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tabIIII">
        <h2>TEST</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tabV">
        <h2>TEST</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
html {
    background-color:black;
}
div {
    background-color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    border:ridge 5px #660066;
    margin:10px;
}
#tabI {
    left:0%;
    position:absolute;
}
#tabII {
    top:8px;
    left:17%;
    position:absolute;
}
#tabIII {
    top:8px;
    left:34%;
    position:absolute;
}
#tabIIII {
    top:8px;
    left:51%;
    position:absolute;
}
#tabV {
    top:8px;
    left:68%;
    position:absolute;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-family:"Lucida Console";
    position:absolute;
    left:35%;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

Annnnddd Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").fadeOut(slow);
});
```

The Jquery library is linked correctly, it may not look like it because formatting, but it is.

Comment: what do you mean by not working? any console errors?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('ok');
});

Does this work?

Comment: It'd help if we could see script.js

Comment: In your js code 'slow' should be written with "" like this: "slow"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: It works in my fiddle (note that I made the change I wrote in my previous comment) http://jsfiddle.net/QQHK7/

Comment: Put your answer in an answer, please.

Comment: I suggest a debugging tool, it can help to detect such problems in run time. I use firebug in firefox, most mainstream browsers have built-in debugging tool also.

Comment: No console errors, Putting quotes around slow dose not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I set up a fiddle to test your case and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QQHK7/

The only thing I changed is I put `""`s around the word slow, as jquery expects either an integer (in milliseconds) or a string (like "slow").

If you write it like you did, jquery is getting an `undefined` variable in the fadeOut function and it freaks out.

Here's the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: That did not fix it, the divs will still not fade out. Nothing happens, no errors, but it dose run in fiddel, which is odd. I am going to check if something is wrong with jquery.js

Comment: In that case you are not including your script correctly. Try writing your script inside the page itself instead of including script.js

Comment: It works now after reinstalling jquery. It dose not run in codecademy which I have been using to test it, I have no idea why. Thanks for the help with the 'slow' thing.

Comment: What do you mean "reinstalling jQuery"? You're not installing it, just loading into your page. Anyway, glad it works.

Comment: I stopped accessing the web version and downloaded the jquery script locally.